# How to remove an element from an array and resize the array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I want to remove a specific object from an array, put it in a smaller array without getting out of range. This is what I've tried but it won't work.

```
Skateboard[] newSkateboard = new Skateboard[_skateboards.Length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < _skateboards.Length; i++)
{
    if (skateboard.Code != _skateboards[i].Code)
    {
        newSkateboard[i] = _skateboards[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use list<t> instead of arrays. Almost
 allways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

```
    var j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _skateboards.Length; i++)
    {
        if (skateboard.Code != _skateboards[i].Code)
        {
            newSkateboard[j] = _skateboards[i];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
```